# redirect/listen to port 8080 if 80 is unreachable, apache to lighttpd

Tags: apache, proxy, iptables, lighttpd, ports

i am running apache and lighty on different ports and want to redirect if apache is down. Do i have to use iptables ?

mod proxy_http is enabled, anything to enable something in lighty?

Are there any suggestions?

edit:
FORWARD chain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like haproxy or lighttpd or nginx in front of Apache, and configure any of them to send the request to other backend hosts/server instances if Apache is down.  (Apache has modules for this, too, so you could run Apache in front of Apache.)

Comment: i consider to use apache twicely